# Accessing headers on Quarkus Graphql

Tags: java, graphql, quarkus, microprofile, smallrye

I'm using Quarkus GraphQL in my project. Defined a class with **@GraphQLApi** and a **@Query** method inside it.
I'm not sure how to access the **HttpHeaders** in the defined method when querying a request.
I tried **@HeaderParam** but I'm getting a null value. There isn't much about the headers in the quarkus documentation either.
Is there a way to get the headers from the **@Query** methods?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GraphQL API itself does not currently offer access to HTTP headers, but you can inject an instance of `CurrentVertxRequest` and read the headers from there:

```
@Inject
CurrentVertxRequest request;

// and in your query method:
request.getCurrent().request().getHeader("My-Header")
```

Comment: You can also inject `RoutingContext` directly. It is returned by the getCurrent method.